# Who discovered or predicted an electron g factor of circa 2?

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm writing a physics article with significant historical content, and I'm struggling to find something. Forgetting about the anomalous magnetic dipole moment for a minute, the electron's [g factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-factor_(physics)#Electron_spin_g-factor) is approximately 2. This is twice the "classical" value.

**Who predicted and/or discovered or measured this g factor of 2?**

I'm currently look at H Stanley Allen's 1921 paper [The Angular Momentum and Some Related Properties of the Ring Electron](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/14786442108636201?journalCode=tphm17). It dates from 1921. He  gives the magnetic moment as 9.232 x 10ˉ²¹ EMU, ½(e/m)(h/2π)

Answer (score 3):

From Crane, H. R. "The g factor of the electron." *Scientific American* 218.1 (1968): 72-85.

Samuel A. Goudsmit and George E. Uhlenbeck proposed

> ... in 1925 that the electron itself had an angular momentum and a
>   magnetic moment. ... That the electron should have in addition an
>   intrinsic magnetic moment was part and parcel of the idea that it was
>   spinning. ... Thus at the time of the discovery of electron spin the g
>   factor of the electron could be expressed as the number of "natural
>   units" of magnetic moment (...) divided by the number of "natural
>   units" of angular momentum (...). When defined in this way, the g
>   factor for the orbital motion of the electron in its lowest energy
>   state in hydrogen is 1, whereas the g factor of the free electron is
>   2. (The g factor as a term designating a ratio of magnetic moment to angular momentum in these special units had been introduced a few
>   years earlier for the case of the atom by the German physicist Alfred
>   Lande.) ... In the case of the g factor of the electron, a strong
>   reinforcement for the belief in the exactness of the value 2 came in
>   the late 1920's from the new formulation of quantum mechanics by P. A.
>   M. Dirac.

Also helpful is Tomonaga, S. *The story of spin*. University of Chicago Press, 1997

From Enz, Charles P. *No time to be brief: A scientific biography of Wolfgang Pauli*. Oxford University Press on Demand, 2010.
Chp. 5 The Hamburg years: The curious history of spin.

"But who should now be considered the discoverer of the electron's spin, Pauli, Kronig, or Uhlenbech and Goudsmit?" [p.116].
"That in the history of modern physics the idea of spin has stirred up so much controversy is a strange fact." [p.119].

From Pais, Abraham. *Inward bound: of matter and forces in the physical world*. Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1986.

"Following a hint by Ehrenfest, George [Uhlenbeck] found in an old article by [M.] Abraham [1903] that an electron considered as a rigid sphere with surface charge only does have g = 2."  [p.277]. Similar proposals to Abraham were made by Fitzgerald [1900], Compton [1921] and Kennard [1922]. Pauli made a proposal of spin which influenced Goudsmit and Uhlenbeck in 1924. [p.279]. Pais quotes Dirac on the Dirac equation, "It was found that this equation gave the particle a spin of half a quantum. And also gave it a magnetic moment. It gave just the properties that one needed for an electron. That was really an unexpected bonus for me, completely unexpected." [p.286].

From Pippard, Brian. "Magnetic Moments." Rev. of *Inward Bound: Of Matter and Forces in the Physical World*, by Abraham Pais. *London Review of Books* 8.15 (1986): 17-18. 16 Nov. 2019 https://www.lrb.co.uk/v08/n15/brian-pippard/magnetic-moments.

> Why should anyone wish to know the magnetic moment of the electron to
>   ten-figure accuracy? The answer is worth giving in some detail as an
>   exemplary account of the research process. We must return to the early
>   days of quantum mechanics and the task Dirac set himself in 1927 to
>   make it consistent with relativity theory, as it was not when first
>   formulated. In one of the masterpieces of physics he showed that the
>   restrictions imposed by relativity, as well as others which he
>   regarded as essential, allowed only one formulation. Applied to the
>   electron, its solutions described, without any extra assumptions, a
>   number of properties which the electron had been found experimentally
>   to possess, but which had not been explained hitherto. Among them was
>   the magnetic moment whose magnitude is conventionally expressed by a
>   number g; in Dirac’s theory g turns out to be exactly 2, and the
>   spectroscopists at the time were satisfied that this agreed with their
>   extremely precise measurements. There was, however, an exceedingly
>   curious consequence of the theory: that it permitted electrons to have
>   negative as well as positive energy, something that is inconceivable
>   in classical mechanics.

[Did anyone mention the possibility of antimatter before 1928?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/11139/did-anyone-mention-the-possibility-of-antimatter-before-1928)

Comment: Thanks for that Michael.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Nature Physics article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-018-0341-3), it appears to have been Paul Dirac:

> From his theory of relativistic quantum mechanics, Paul Dirac predicted that the g-factor of elementary spin-1/2 particles, such as the electron, is exactly 2.

Further corrections to this value come from QED.